# Pascal - How to pass variable number of parameters to a subprogram ? (variadic function)

Tags: arguments, parameter-passing, pascal, variadic-functions

I recently had to face this problem, which is, how can I pass 1, 2, 3, 9, 38919, 0 or any random number of arguments to a function or a procedure in Pascal ? I want to make a subprogram that accepts as many parameters as I want to pass it, like writeln.

```
 writeln('Hello, ', name, '.');
 writeln('You were born on ', birthDate, ', and you are ', age, ' years old.');
```

I searched the web for some guide or whatever, but the only related threads I found were [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916616/passing-variable-number-of-arguments) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836272/passing-variable-number-of-arguments), which helped me understanding my problem a bit more, but I still don't know how to do this in Pascal. 
I also found [this](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=11086.0), but I'm not sure I really understood what it says. (and I don't know either if what applies to Free Pascal applies to other compilers too)

Any ideas ? :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and for all, writeln is a language construct, and not a function. You can't imitate it for your own functions. (you can reroute writeln output though, and FPC has [writestr](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/writestr.html) that can writeln to string)

The [array of const](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu69.html#x181-20300014.4.6) syntax is more Delphi oriented. [Open array](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu68.html#x180-20200014.4.5) is Delphi oriented too, but Turbo Pascal had a own form. It is only for one type though.

But since classic pascal has no way of doing variadic parameters, if you want this, you can't avoid using extensions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I'll use an "array of const"-like method to solve my problem, because I think it's the closest way to do what I want. Thank your for the links !