# Pascal variable number of function arguments

Tags: variadic-functions, pascal

I want to realize the next function on Pascal

```
unsigned long SUBSTRINGS(sqlrcur *curref, ... )
{
    va_list ap;
    int argc, I;
.....
}
```

How can I do it on Pascal? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Pascal),

> Standard Pascal does not allow variadic functions.
>
> See [Free Pascal](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Free_Pascal) instead.

See also [Pascal - How to pass variable number of parameters to a subprogram ? (variadic function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654438/pascal-how-to-pass-variable-number-of-parameters-to-a-subprogram-variadic-f)

Comment: Free Pascal supports variadic functions, but mostly only of its own safe type (array of const). It can call unsafe C variadic functions though, but not define unsafe C type variadic functions